# How do I convert a json array with a single value into a key value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json payload that is an array with a single value and I want to convert it into a Key : Value pair

Payload

```
{
    "results": [22390]
}
```

Required

```
{
    "results": 22390
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: There's no such thing as a json array. That's an object with a property that has an array as its value.

Comment: Why do you want to "unwrap" the number? The property suggests that there can be more than one value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be:

```
let obj = { "results": [22390] };
obj = {"results": obj.results[0]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post - I need to keep the Constant the same name, so I am looking to update / overwrite the value in the results property

Comment: Sure, the change is very simple. I edited my answer to meet your need

Comment: The json payload has already been assigned to a constant  so I cannot use a constant or variable. I need to change the format either by changing the Object property to a value instead of the array or create a new Key Value pair on the payload directly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all it needed was to read the first array value back into the Key.

```
results=results[0];

{
 "results": 22390
}
```